# LayerDrawable to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I'm using a LayerDrawable to merge multiple Drawable. Now, I'd like to export my LayerDrawable to a file.

I've tried this way:

```
Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)myLayerDrawable).getBitmap();
--> ClassCastException...
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried drawing the Drawable to a Bitmap Canvas? I think the call order would go something like:

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config);
myLayerDrawable.draw(new Canvas(b));
```

Then you can write the Bitmap object to an output stream.

Comment: Thanks. I think something is wrong: with W=550, H=550, config=ARGB_8888, I end up with W & H = -1 for the Bitmap b. If I export it to a file, the picture is well sized but totally blank...

Comment: Try calling setBounds on the Drawable. If you don't tell it what to draw, it won't draw anything.

Comment: Thanks! And I finally discovered why I have never been able to do something with Bitmap.createBitmap :)

Answer (score 7):

Thank both users have answered before me ([@Kyle P](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4101545/5318303) and [@Anjum Shrimali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6936433/5318303)). Inspired by their answers ... This worked for my case fine:

```
final int width = myLayerDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
final int height = myLayerDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
myLayerDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
myLayerDrawable.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the help. But a beginner like me need some more specific code. I tried and its working for me the following.

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
layerDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
layerDrawable.draw(new Canvas(b));
```

Ultimately the b (Bitmap) is the desired combined bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody wants a kotlin version of the **@Mir-Ismaili's** answers

```
val height = layerDrawable.intrinsicHeight
val width = layerDrawable.intrinsicWidth
val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
layerDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height)
layerDrawable.draw(Canvas(bitmap))
```